# MS Access Control Value

Tags: vba, ms-access

MS Access and VBA seem to have built-in conversion of data-types. For example, there is a textbox control in my form and I see it referenced in either of these two ways:

```
If Form!transaction_type = "Credit Card"

If Form!transaction_type.Value = "Credit Card"
```

What is the significance of the Value property of the transaction_type control? Can someone direct me to some documentation on the Value property, when to use it and when not to use it, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For convenience, objects often have a default property. That allows for the notation of your 1st example, which at first glance seems to assign a string value to the *object* itself. What's actually going on behind the scenes is that VBA assigns the data to the default property, which in this case is `.Value`. You can yourself mimic that behavior in VBA with classes you create. There's a way in the VBA Editor to do it, but on the machine I'm currently sitting, I have no Office installed. What it does is basically editing the class file with these values: https://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?839161-Default-Class-Properties-and-Let-Get

I'm personally not a big fan of relying on that mechanic, as it leads to the kind of confusion you are experiencing. And while it would be a pretty bad way of doing things, imagine the original author changes the default property in a future version of the object. All of a sudden your code at best breaks and errors out and at worst still works, but causes hard to track bugs. If instead of relying on the default property, you always addressed it directly, your code wouldn't be impacted by that change and keeps on working correctly.

Edit:
*(I originally linked to the VB.NET documentation for creating a default property, which is [Default Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/procedures/how-to-declare-and-call-a-default-property))*